# "Google Docs encountered an error" on embedded Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, iframe

I have a web page which embeds several parts of a Google Spreadsheet
http://nkelsey.x10.mx/GTC/Members_Area/WinterSinglesLeague/singlesleaguetablesorig.html

This page has worked for years unaltered. We just edit the spreadsheet and the web pages updates automatically.... only for the last few weeks we have been encountering 'Google Docs encountered an error' messages where the parts of the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11JxbhDbTiXP106rx7p9uB0qHImZG5TeIH0JReGUeWRo/edit#gid=44) should be.
[image: Web page errors]

I did raise the issue with Google One support but after clarifying the issue after a few hours the report was 'closed' by Google with no response!
I tried making a copy of the spreadsheet and embedding that - again Google Errors were observed.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

I have checked the 'Share' on the spreadsheet and it is correctly set to 'View' and the sheet is 'published'. There are no 'hidden' columns or rows.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page source, it appears that the embedded link does not match the spreadsheet. I would suggest trying to replace that link with the one from **File** > **Publish to the web** > **Embed**, carrying over the parameters listed on the [Docs Editors help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Cembed-a-document-spreadsheet-or-presentation%2Cembed-a-form%2Cedit-embedded-spreadsheets) from the original URL.